# How to get a value from a promise within a recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I'm working with NodeJs and Box SDK.

I need to get data on all the files and folders inside a directory, so I'm checking every folder for child folders and files, saving the data in an array, and then calling the function again if there were any child folders.

The problem is that I can't get the array with all the data from within the recursive calls, I can't figure out where to return or resolve my function `checkChilds`, nor handle the promises.

What I need is a promise that will resolve once the for loop finishes and all the stacks are completed so `arrayIds` will have all the data when everything is done.

The folder structure in my main directory is divided in Preview and Production, so I'm also checking where it belongs in the array.

This is my code:

```
var boxUtil = require('../utils/boxUtils')
var boxInstance = boxUtil.getBOXInstance()

exports.script = function (request, response) {
  var accessToken = request.headers.authorization
  var folderId = request.body.folderId
  var userId = request.body.user

  var arrayIds = []

  boxInstance = boxUtil.getBOXInstance()
  if (boxInstance == null) {
    boxUtil.initBOXInstance(userId, function (error, res) {
      if (error) {
        response.status(500)
        return response.send(error.message)
      }
      boxInstance = res
      var box = boxInstance.getBasicClient(accessToken)

      var func = getFolderInfo(folderId, arrayIds, box)
      .then(checkIfPreviewOrProduction)
      .then(insertInPreviewOrProduction)
      .then(iAmRecursive)
      .then(stringLogMe)
      .then(null, console.log)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('RESTART SERVER AND TRY AGAIN PLEASE')
  }
}

function iAmRecursive ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function checkChilds ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
      if (resp.item_collection.total_count > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < resp.item_collection.entries.length; j++) {
          if (resp.item_collection.entries[j].type === 'folder') {
            getFolderInfo(resp.item_collection.entries[j].id, arrayIds, boxInstance)
              .then(insert)
              .then(checkChilds)
              .then(null, console.log)
          }
          if (resp.item_collection.entries[j].type === 'file') {
            ifFileChild([resp.item_collection.entries[j], arrayIds, boxInstance])
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log('no childs were found')
      }
    }
    checkChilds([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
  })
}

function stringLogMe (stringifyMe) {
  var text = console.log(JSON.stringify(stringifyMe, null, 2))
  return text
}

function getFolderInfo (folderId, arrayIds, boxInstance) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var query = {fields: 'id,name,item_collection,path_collection'}
    boxInstance.folders.get(folderId, query, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
      }
    })
  })
}

function getMetadata ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var fileId = resp.id
    boxInstance.files.getAllMetadata(fileId, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        response.name = resp.name
        response.type = resp.type
        resolve([response, arrayIds, boxInstance])
      }
    })
  })
}

function insert ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (resp.type === 'file') {
      var newObject = {
        'id': resp.id,
        'name': resp.name,
        'type': resp.type,
        'entries': resp.entries
      }
    } else {
      var newObject = {
        id: resp.id,
        name: resp.name,
        type: resp.type
      }
    }
    arrayIds.push(newObject)
    resolve([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
  })
}

function ifFileChild ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getMetadata([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
    .then(insert)
    .then(null, console.log)
  })
}
```

My function `iAmRecursive` is the one supposed to resolve with the full array in the promise chain.

I've read several similar questions but I couldn't make anything work with my recursive calls.

Please let me know if you need more clarification on the problem.

Comment: This is a lot of code. Could you try isolating the problem? Without even looking at it or understanding what the problem is: first collect all the names recursively, then use `Promise.all` on the result.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I just edited the code to make a little simpler. The thing is, how do I know when the recursive function will have collected all the names? Because right now my function `iAmRecursive`and `checkChilds` are not returning or resolving any result. 
I've tried resolving the promise several times but it didnt work. 
Should I return `checkChilds`? And resolve it at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the function a bit. It will now collect all the promises and resolve once they all resolve.

```
function iAmRecursive([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {

  var promises = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < resp.item_collection.entries.length; j++) {
    if (resp.item_collection.entries[j].type === 'folder') {
      promises.push(getFolderInfo(resp.item_collection.entries[j].id, arrayIds, boxInstance)
        .then(insert)
        .then(iAmRecursive)
        .then(null, console.log)
      )
    }
    if (resp.item_collection.entries[j].type === 'file') {
      promises.push(ifFileChild([resp.item_collection.entries[j], arrayIds, boxInstance]));
    }
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);

}
```

Edit due to comments. You are not resolving some of your promises.

Change

```
function ifFileChild ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getMetadata([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
    .then(insert)
    .then(null, console.log)
  })
}
```

To

```
function ifFileChild ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return getMetadata([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
    .then(insert)
    .then(null, console.log)
}
```

It's redundant to create a new promise if you are going to immediately resolve it with another. But if you had to, if for example there were other, asynchronous resolve branches, you'd want something like this:

```
function ifFileChild ([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance]) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if( /* condition*/){
      setTimeout(function(){ resolve("jea"); }, 5000);
    }
    else{
      resolve( getMetadata([resp, arrayIds, boxInstance])
      .then(insert)
      .then(null, console.log)
      )
    }
  })
}
```

You can use this to flatten the array:

```
var flat = (function flatten(result, current){
  return result.concat( Array.isArray(current) ? current.reduce(flatten, []) : current )
})([], array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!
I ran the code with the `return` statements and what it does now is to check first 4 folders and when it doesn't find any more childs it logs _no childs were found_ and stops the whole function instead of just stopping that stack.

Comment: The `else` branch too has to be resolved. See if it works now.

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work, it looks like we are resolving the whole function too early.

Comment: The code works better now! But the response is not right, I'm getting:
[
  [
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [
          null,
          null
        ]
      ],
      [],
      [
        null,
        null
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [
          null,
          null
        ]
      ],
      [],
      [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
When I expect a flat array like:
[
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
 {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]

Comment: Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: If I console.log while it is looping inside the recursion I see the array getting filled correctly every time, but the response I get from the Promise.all is the one above with the null.

Comment: The thing is, whenever there is children you promise to collect them with `Promise.all` which resolves with an array of what each child resolved with. The result you're getting is correct. You have to either flatten it afterwards, or push to an array in the outer scope directly when reaching leaves.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. 
I can't get the right response, depending if I console log or console.log(JSON.stryngify()), and where/when, I end up with empty arrays, with null, or two arrays with Object object inside.
At what time should I push to an array in the outer scope?